# load interpreted php file in simplexml

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

Script xmlmake.php loads a file, parses it's contents, and outputs (echoes) xml elements. Thus when opened in a browser http://domain.com/xmlmake.php ouputs a well formated xml file.

I would like for another script to load the file via simplexml but through a relative path eg.

```
 <?php simplexml_load_file('../system/xmlmake.php'); ?>
```

and **not** like this

```
<?php simplexml_load_file('http://domain.com/xmlmake.php'); ?>
```

So in layman terms 'open an interpreted php file' with simplexml...
All this so the files can be moved outside the public_html folder, thus cannot be accessed in browser.

Comment: As an alternative to making an HTTP request to get the script executed, you could as well include it and use the output buffer to capture its output. (Provided the script will work when “imported” into the current scope this way.)

Answer (score 1):

you must first "download file", by doing somethong like this

```
$a = file_get_contents('http://http://stackoverflow.com/');
file_put_contents ('data.tmp',$a);
simplexml_load_file('data.tmp');
unlink('data.tmp');
```

**Update**

To write a lot less code, and to avoid storing file you can do simply this:

```
 $a = file_get_contents('http://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml');
 echo "$a";
```

Comment: Iguess that would work, same as if the script would not echo the xml but save the xml in a separate file. I'm wondering if there is a qay to skip that step.

Comment: @user2982427 , I've update my answer, I hope that can be helpful